# How to stop another already running script in python?

Tags: python, import, os.system

There is a way to start another script in python by doing this:

```
import os

os.system("python [name of script].py")
```

So how can i stop another already running script? I would like to stop the script by using the name.

Comment: You can kill the script using the pid or name, can you add a little more context?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i would like to stop by using the name

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am running the scripts on Raspberry Pi, the script I am trying to stop is written by myself.

Comment: running   `pkill -9 -f script.py` will kill the script

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Can I implement this into code?

Comment: I added an example of how but if you use subprocess to start the script a per mhawkes answer it will be  easy to kill it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is more usual to *import* the other script and then invoke its functions and methods.

If that does not work for you, e.g. the other script is not written in such a way that is conducive to being imported, then you can use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module to start another process.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script.py', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
# continue with your code then terminate the child
p.terminate()
```

There are many possible ways to control and interact with the child process, e.g. you can can capture its stdout and sterr, and send it input. See the [`Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) documentation.

Answer (score 5):

If you start the script as per  mhawkes suggestion is it a better option but to answer your question of how to kill an already started script by name you can use [pkill](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) and [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

```
from subprocess import check_call
import sys

script = sys.argv[1]


check_call(["pkill", "-9", "-f", script])
```

Just pass the name to kill:

```
padraic@home:~$ cat kill.py
from subprocess import check_call
import sys

script = sys.argv[1]


check_call(["pkill", "-9", "-f", script])


padraic@home:~$ cat test.py
from time import sleep

while True:
   sleep(1)
padraic@home:~$ python test.py &
[60] 23361
padraic@home:~$ python kill.py test.py
[60]   Killed             python test.py
Killed
```

That kills the process with a `SIGKIll`, if you want to terminate remove the -9:

```
padraic@home:~$ cat kill.py
from subprocess import check_call
import sys

script = sys.argv[1]

check_call(["pkill", "-f", script])


padraic@home:~$ python test.py &
[61] 24062
padraic@home:~$ python kill.py test.py 
[61]   Terminated              python test.py
Terminated
```

That will send a `SIGTERM`. [Termination-Signals](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html)

Comment: Hi @Padraic Cunningham, your script worked well for me. However, when I tried to tweak it a bit (replaced sys.argv[1] with the path to my script --> 'home/pi/MotionDetector.py') it threw an error :"  CalledProcessError: Command '['pkill', '-9', '-f', '/home/pi/MotionDetector.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1"

Can you pls help?

Answer (score 0):

Just put in the name of the program NOT the path to your script.
so it would be

```
check_call(["pkill", "-f", "MotionDetector.py"])
```