# Python stop running script using another script

Tags: python

So I have a python file that runs nonstop. I know I can end it by pressing `Control + C` but I need to do this using another script.

Is there a script equivalent to pressing `Control + C` ?

Comment: `Ctrl + C` will send a _signal_ to that process. You can send signals programmatically: [kill(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) and [kill(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop another already running script in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676205/how-to-stop-another-already-running-script-in-python)