# Terminating an already running python script using another python script

Tags: javascript, python, html

When a button is clicked in my HTML,let us say "connect" button, it will execute a python script. What I wanted to do is when another button, say "disconnect", is clicked, the python script which was previously launched will be terminated. I searched for answers already but I can't get it right. I thought of launching another python script that will eventually terminate the already running script. would that be possible?

from **JS**

```
function connect(){
$.ajax({
       url: "python-scripts/connect.py",
       success: function(response) { 
       }
    });
}
function disconnect(){
$.ajax({
       url: "python-scripts/disconnect.py",
       success: function(response) { 
       }
    });
}
```

**connect.py**

```
while True:
   print "test"
```

i want **disconnect.py** to terminate **connect.py** 
I saw these answered questions but I do not know how to properly use it in python since I am still new to it.
[Terminate a python script from another python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054740/terminate-a-python-script-from-another-python-script)
[How to stop another already running script in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676205/how-to-stop-another-already-running-script-in-python)

or atleast, can somebody tell me how this works?

```
from subprocess import check_call
import sys

script = sys.argv[1]


check_call(["pkill", "-9", "-f", script])
```

Comment: please post the code you've tried.

Comment: @sam-pyt oh I'm sorry. I edited it already

Comment: ok this type of thing depends on OS, so are you Windows? Unix or MacOS?

Comment: @sam-pyt Windows

Comment: I just saw your links up there. you won't get much better answers for this question than those.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd like to know how this works. I added something at my question @sam-pyt