# Kill a python script from another script - CalledProcessError

Tags: python, kill-process

I want to kill a python script that runs on my system from another python script.

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36676497/4276413) and tweaked the code a bit, but got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/pi/base.py", line 13, in <module>
    check_call(["pkill", "-9", "-f", script])
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  CalledProcessError: Command '['pkill', '-9', '-f', '/home/pi/MotionDetector.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Code:

```
from subprocess import check_call
import sys
import time

script = '/home/pi/MotionDetector.py'
check_call(["pkill", "-9", "-f", script])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was just a bug.

The solution was simple, I copied my script to a new file, deleted the old one and it worked, simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

This means the `pkill` call has failed. Two possible reasons that come to mind:

- it did not actually match any process. `pkill` would in this case not generate any output and return `1`. You can verify this by trying to run `pgrep` instead of `pkill` and see what did it return on `stdout` (should be one or more lines with a PID in case of a match) and/or whether it also returned a non-zero status.
- it did match, but user under which the pkill has been executed cannot kill the process(s) matched. In that case `pkill` should generate output on `stderr` similar to: `pkill: killing pid 3244 failed: Operation not permitted`

From the `pkill(1)` man page:

> ```
> EXIT STATUS
> ...
>        1      No processes matched or none of them could be signalled.
> ...
> ```

Comment: If it's the first case, how can it be resolved? If it's the second - how can I add sudo or get elevated privileges?

Comment: @Json I would suggest two things: when the script is running, run `ps -ewwo pid,argsps -efw` and identify the process(es) you're looking for. You can also paste it here and we can have a look at it together. My initial guess is either a typo, or the script is not actually called as expected and there is something different about command line as seen in the process listing (matched by `pkill`). You can also try starting with `pgrep -f /home/pi/MotionDetector.py` and combined with information obtained above safely experiment to find a match (expected PIDs are displayed).

Comment: I tried the first command and got this error: error: ' unknown user-defined format specifier "argsps" '

Comment: I've tried to write the info to a file with the command below, but the file was empty
pgrep -f /home/pi/MotionDetector.py >log.txt 2>&1

Comment: My apology that was an editing blunder of mine: `ps -ewwo pid,args`

Comment: So yeah, no match. Please try the other command and read through it's output. My gut would say the path is not exactly the same, perhaps the process of interest used a relative one on the command line?

Comment: Thanks, it works. so I get a long list of all my processes including the MotionDetector script with shows up like this:
'23538 python /home/pi/MotionDetector.py'

Comment: Now I am really stomped. So, here you indeed see `/home/pi/MotionDetector.py` as part of `python /home/pi/MotionDetector.py` running with pid `23538`, but if you at that time (or at any other time with corresponding pid) `pgrep -f /home/pi/MotionDetector.py`, it does not print `23538`. Assuming no copy/paste problem, there seems to be no mismatch between the actual and `pgrep`ed for string. Are we talking about one machine? Or is there some network access, VM, container involved between the runs? Could we be looking in a wrong place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180294/discussion-between-ondrej-k-and-json).