# How to kill a python script through another script under condition

Tags: python, tcp, raspberry-pi, operating-system

I want to call 2 python scripts using tcp Conditionally via another main script.
So, when my data sent to the main script is "YES", the first script executed and when data = "No", the second script executed! the problem is that when the data sent "YES" the first script runs, but when the data sent "No", the second one does not execute, so I realized that I have to add a condition to kill the first one in order to run the second and vice versa, so how can I do it? Help me, please!

```
#main script
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import socket
backlog = 1
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('192.168.43.95', 12345))
s.listen(backlog)
try:
    print ("is waiting")
    client, address = s.accept()
    while True:
        data = client.recv(size)
        if data == "YES \n":
            os.system('python script1.py')
        elif data == "No \n":
            os.system('python script2.py')
except:
    print("closing socket")
    client.close()
    s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether you need to kill the script all depends on how you want the program to behave.
`os.system()` is blocking. That means that the main script is NOT executing (is blocked) while whatever you called with `os.system()` is running - in your case that's either `python script1.py` or `python script2.py`. So if you send "YES" and after that "No", would get started and script2 will get executed only *after script1 has finished*.

If you want the execution of script1 and script2 happen concurrently, you should use `Popen` from the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) library.

If you want to kill the script that started running first when you got a new command (generally not a good idea, but there are uses for it), you can use `Popen.kill()`.

Comment: I just want them to run in an alternative way when the first runs the second ends and vice versa and all in a loop!

Comment: I saw the solution you offered me in another location https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676205/how-to-stop-another-already-running-script-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1  but it seems a bit complicated, is there a simpler solution?

Comment: @ninpi if you want them to just alternate, why even bother with recognising whether it's a "YES" or "No"?

Comment: I want to control using a toggle (button) these two scripts if the button in position 1 script 1 runs otherwise script 2 runs!

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
tcpSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

to use same address again

Comment: but I used the tcp login script only in the main script!

Comment: what about if i have to use in both scripts 1 &2 login tcp and in the main script too (in 3 scripts), i added this line to script 1 &2  it shows me an error that i used the same adress! can you help me please!